Using latches to capture 8086 bus
Following with that great answer Reverse engineer LCD Protocol used in MPC2000XL
The Latches are LS374
I'm trying to capture the data using stm32, I have used two latches as the following diagram

and this is the schematic of the bus for your reference
I'm not getting any LCD commands that was referenced in the answer, I only get two LCD Commands 0x60, and CS1,CS2 = 1, A1 = 0 or 1, and they are always like that.
I'm not sure how to debug that, I need some ways to debug that issue.
Here is my coding part:
void processData(uint32_t buffer) {
    // Extracting control signals
    uint32_t data_word = buffer;
    int16_t A1 = (data_word >> 0) & 0x01;  // PD0
    int16_t CS1 = (data_word >> 1) & 0x01; // PD1
    int16_t CS2 = (data_word >> 2) & 0x01; // PD2
    
    // Extracting data bits
    uint8_t data_bits = (data_word >> 3) & 0xFF; // PD3 to PD10

    // Control logic for LCD1 and LCD2
    if ((!CS1) && (!A1)) {
        LCD1_write_cmd(data_bits);
    }
    if ((!CS1) && (A1)) {
        LCD1_write_dat(data_bits);
    }
    if ((!CS2) && (!A1)) {
        LCD2_write_cmd(data_bits);
    }
    if ((!CS2) && (A1)) {
        LCD2_write_dat(data_bits);
    }
}


You use your other account to double-post the same question. I'm afraid that this will not save you from a closed question. ;-) Anyway, your circuit looks correct, if it reflects the actual hardware.

You can ignore cycles with CS1=1 and CS2=1 as they don't address the LCD. If you don't receive cycles for the LCD, the firmware is stuck somewhere else and does not try to access it. -- The next step is to record signals to make sure that your software receives actual values. Use the rising edge of IOWR as trigger, this is the trailing edge of the write cycle. Please [edit] your question to add the results. -- After deciding whether this is a hardware or software issue, please delete one of the questions.

@thebusybee I deleted the other question. I'm not sure about the steps you mentioned. You mean I should while STM firmware is running, to record the signals using logic analyzer ? store them in a text file ?

Well, you write, "I only get two LCD Commands 0x60, and CS1,CS2 = 1, A1 = 0 or 1, and they are always like that." I interpret this as the STM is triggered by the raising edge of IOWR but sees only CS1=1 and CS2=1 and 0x60 as data. If this is not correct, please [edit] your question to make clear what you really get. -- And I meant that you can use your logic analyzer to verify that these values are actually on the wires.

@thebusybee yes my statement is valid and true. So you want me to capture the signals at the input of the latches ?

Yes. To decide where exactly the problem is, you will need to check each step in the path, and I think this is a good starting point.

But as I said, if you only catch cycles with CS1=1 and CS2=1, there are no accesses to the LCD.

@thebusybee at first two break points, I get access to the LCD but can't see what commands they are sent in live view debugger, then CS=1,CS=2, and it stuck on 0x60 as LCD Commands forever

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
